# Workflow Foundation 4 - How to create a web based representation of the workflow?

Tags: asp.net, workflow-foundation-4

We have to write a ASP.NET site based on a workflow.

The client wants to see a graphical representation of the workflow. In addition (let's say it is a workflow for processing orders), the client wants to see at what point in the workflow any given order is, indicated on the graphical workflow representation by a highlighted node or some visual queue.

All of this must be available via a web interface.

Was hoping somebody had some bright ideas for how to achieve this without writing extensive custom controls.

Does Workflow Foundation 4 offer anything itself that would assist toward this end?

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to use the WorkflowDesigner and issue the save image command through code but as it's a WPF control it needs to be hosted on a WPF form. I have tried to do this from a webpage but as the form isn't visible it has a size of 0. I didn't spend a lot of time in this so it might be possible.

See [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wfprerelease/thread/b781c8df-608a-485a-80e3-a795d800f08d) for details on how to do so.

Comment: Found this some time ago but don't implemented yet, I think it may help http://blogs.msdn.com/b/flow/archive/2011/08/16/how-to-save-wf4-workflow-definition-to-image-using-code.aspx